# Any idea, example for Reload Page using Nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript, reload, angular2-nativescript

I'm to search for a example that Reload page in Nativescript.

My app want some time for search data in service, I'm waiting some seconds to display all data, for this I think that is a good idea to put a Reload page. I have a image that demonstrate that I want.[image]

Have you any idea how to implement a Reload page?

Thanx

Comment: what have you tired? AFAIK there's an example in the docs

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by putting `*ngIf` on all the content you want to hide until the loading is done, and the opposite logic on an `ActivityIndicator`.

Here is a sample to achieve it

```
<StackLayout width="100%" height="100%" orientation="vertical" horizontalAlignment="center">
    <StackLayout *ngIf="isLoading" class="vertical-center horizontal-center">
        <ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading">
        </ActivityIndicator>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="!isLoading">
        ... your page content here
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and a little bit of css

```
.vertical-center {
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
}

.horizontal-center {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
}
```